# enc28j60 ordere wrong resistors

Tags: resistors, ethernet, replacement

i prototype a small board with ENC28j60. 
[image]

Instead of 49.9 resistors I have ordered by mistake 47R ones,

What do you think? will it work? It is only 10M ethernet

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but it is (will be) a mistake anyway.

Ethernet has some "tolerance budget" to deal with "non-perfect" environments. Using initially "non(-so)-perfect" design (47R instead of 49R9) you decreases the initial "tolerance budget" leaving a lesser rest (margin) to compensate the "non-perfection" ("non-ideality") of the environment.

Begin the prototyping with what you already have (47R) but don't forget to replace the mistakenly ordered resistors with the recommended (49R9) when you get the correct resistors.